# I got upvote to answer with +4 rep

Tags: bug, reputation, upvotes

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30102122) a question with score +4 (4/0), the answer was accepted and the total score is 49. It should be 55 (40 + 15).

One upvote has +4 reputation, instead of +10. Is it a system fault, or there is something I don't know about? I don't check my reputation tab regularly but I mean all upvotes had always +10.

Screenshot from my reputation tab:
[image: Screenshot from my reputation tab]

Answer (score 5):

You hit the rep cap for the day.

Comment: You're right! I meant the daily limit is higher (today I have rep. +290), but 200 daily limit is just for up/downvotes, exclude accepted answers. It's the point.